# Can applications using old versions of Opengl still run on newer cards?

Tags: opengl

OpenGl 3.0 and up has a quite big difference from the older versions like OpenGl 2.x and opengl 1.x in terms of implementation, does that mean applications which are written with the old versions of opengl won't run on computers having video cards supporting Opengl 3.x and up?

Sorry, if this is not the right place to ask this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the  [OpenGL article on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL#Releases):

> OpenGL releases are backwards compatible. In general, graphics cards released after the OpenGL version release dates shown below support those version features, and all earlier features